# How to prove is $y_n=0$ or not for this sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, numerical-methods

Consider a sequence below

$y_0-y_0(\frac{x}{n})=y_1$

$y_1-y_1(\frac{x}{n})=y_2$

.

.

.

$y_{n-1}-y_{n-1}(\frac{x}{n})=y_n$

From the above sequence,$\frac{x}{n}$ is step size, $y_1=y_0(1-\frac{x}{n})$ and $y_2=y_1(1-\frac{x}{n})$ so $y_n=y_0(1-\frac{x}{n})^n$
when n tend to infinity, $y_n=y_0e^{-x}$

or can solve using $\frac{dy}{dx}=-y$, assuming $y(0)=y_0$ to show that for sequence above for x>0, $y_n$ wont be touching the point $y=0$ for all x

However, now i been thinking if sequence change to the condition below

$y_0^a-y_0^b(\frac{x}{n})=y_1^a$

$y_1^a-y_1^b(\frac{x}{n})=y_2^a$

.

.

.

$y_{n-1}^a-y_{n-1}^b(\frac{x}{n})=y_n^a$

and by not using the DE $\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{y^b}{ay^{a-1}}$ , is it able to show if $a>b$, $y_n$ will eventually touche the point $y=0$, for $b>a$ it wont touch the point $y=0$ for all $x$

Comment: The second half makes no sense. Is that supposed to represent the Euler method of numerical ODE integration?

Comment: Sorry there a typo. Changed $y_n^b to y_n^a$ on the second half right hand side equation. For the first sequence $E=y$ and $\frac{dE}{dx}=-y$ so by chain rule $\frac{dy}{dx}=-y$ and this appear to be Euler method. For the second half, i treat $E=y^a$ and $\frac{dE}{dx}=-y^b$ since $\frac{x}{n}$ can be treated like dx when n tend to infinity. So can derive what $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is. If this not true, then how about proving the case a=1,b>1 and a=1,b<1, will y touches 0 for all x without using numerical ODE integration?